# Google Search from Linux Terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, linux-terminal

I saw a Google console app someone wrote a while back, but it was actually a website emulating a console.

What I'm after is a shortcut or Linux terminal app which I can use to quickly search Google.

Ideally, it will show the top 10 search results with numbers next to them, and pressing the number will open the site in a browser.

Having the Google results open in a browser is fine too.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The website emulating a console - are you talking of goosh? http://goosh.org/

Comment: you will end up open the browser anyway, whats the point?

Comment: the point is to issue google searches from the terminal where we spend most of our time and are most comfortable. it might also be neat to have your recent google searches all visible in a command line history.

Comment: Closed as off-topic? Can it not just be migrated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[google-cli](https://github.com/jarun/google-cli)** is supposed to do just that (it's the revived version of [cli-google](https://github.com/henux/cli-google)).

Answer (score 28):

Here's a simple bash function that lets you type

```
google foo bar
```

and which will then open your default browser to display the Google results page for those search terms:

```
google() {
    search=""
    echo "Googling: $@"
    for term in $@; do
        search="$search%20$term"
    done
    xdg-open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$search"
}
```

Simply paste that in your terminal to give it a try.

For Windows or Mac OS X, substitute the last line with one of the following (assuming you are using Cygwin or similar on Windows):

Windows

```
start "http://www.google.com/search?q=$search"
```

Mac OS X

```
open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$search"
```

Comment: i turned this into a shell script for mac by changing xdg-open to open, removing the function part and then adding script to bin. Thanks!

Comment: simply gold!!!!

Comment: If you are using oh-my-zsh, try the web-search plugin --> https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/web-search

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(echo $*) ]]; then

    searchterm="$*"

else

    read -p "Enter your search term: " searchterm

fi

searchterm=$(echo $searchterm | sed -e 's/\ /+/g')

lynx -dump http://www.google.com/search?q=$searchterm | less
```

Copy and paste this script into `~/bin`, name it "goose" or something (GOOgle SEarch). Chmod it +x

Usage is:

```
goose searchterm
```

Clearly, you have to have Lynx installed.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to search from the command line and jump to a user-definable browser for results, another solution is use [surfraw](http://surfraw.gitlab.io/).

```
   Surfraw  provides  a fast unix command line interface to a variety of
   popular WWW search engines and other artifacts of power.  It reclaims
   google,  altavista, dejanews, freshmeat, research index, slashdot and
   many others from the false‐prophet,  pox‐infested  heathen  lands  of
   html‐forms,  placing  these  wonders  where they belong, deep in unix
   heartland, as god loving extensions to the shell.
```

It's available pre-packaged in some Linux distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, unknown others), <s>from source at debian.org</s>, and the latest development code and [releases](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw/tags) are available from the [official git repository](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw) (now living on GitLab).

[Installation instructions](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw/wikis/Installation) from tarball or deb file are found on the [Wiki](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw/wikis/home).

Trivia note : Surfraw was originally written by Julian Assange.  (Acronym/backronym for 'SURFRAW' is Shell Users' Revolutionary Front Rage Against the World Wide Web.)

To do a Google search from the command line:
`sr google archibald tuttle`

In addition to plain old Google, there are a lot of other built in search types.

To search for an RFC dealing with S/MIME:
`sr rfc s/mime`

Translate a word:
`sr translate logiciel`

Find torrents:
`sr piratebay free music`

(These keyword search types continue to be updated.)

[More advanced usage](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw/wikis/Usage) :

```
     $ surfraw google -results=100 RMS, GNU, which is sinner, which is sin?
     $ sr wikipedia surfraw
     $ sr austlii -method=phrase dog like
     $ /usr/lib/surfraw/rhyme -method=perfect Julian
```

[Surfraw is configurable](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw/wikis/Configuration). You can set it up with some defaults, either per-user in `$HOME/.surfraw.conf` or system-wide in `/etc/surfraw.conf` :

```
SURFRAW_graphical_browser="/usr/bin/links2 -g"
SURFRAW_text_browser="/usr/bin/elinks"
SURFRAW_graphical=yes
```

Here I've set it to use links2 and elinks, but you can use Firefox, Chrome, or any others you prefer.

(Nb. `links2 -g` is a strange terminal-embedded graphical-mode browser.  It's fast but hates modernity.)

Answer (score 5):

With `wget`, example:

```
wget -U 'Firefox/3.0.15' http://www.google.com/search?q=wget+google+query+to+file -O file.html
```

[Source](http://isaksen.biz/blog/?p=470)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small application to allow you to do a Google search via CLI, it is actually very simple and currently only supports Web search, Images search and News search.

Codename: [Gisele](https://github.com/borisguery/Gisele)

```
$ php gisele.phar web -m 5 "stackoverflow"
1) Stack Overflow - http://stackoverflow.com/
2) Ask Question - http://stackoverflow.com/users/login
3) Stack overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow
4) Blog Stack Exchange - http://blog.stackexchange.com/
5) StackOverflow - IT Conversations - The Conversations Network - http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Lynx - a general purpose distributed information browser for the World Wide Web. Lynx  is a fully-featured World Wide Web (WWW) client for users running cursor-addressable, character-cell display devices (e.g., vt100 terminals, vt100 emulators running on Windows 95/NT or Macintoshes, or any other "curses-oriented" display).

It  will  display  hypertext  markup  language (HTML)  documents  containing  links to files residing on the local system, as well as files residing on remote systems running Gopher, HTTP, FTP, WAIS, and NNTP servers.  Current versions of Lynx run on Unix, VMS, Windows 95/NT, 386DOS and OS/2 EMX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use w3m - a text based browser. You can open any website with it on terminal. In short you can have google in your terminal and search from there. If you are interested check this [link.](http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/google-terminal-ubuntu-linux/)

To install w3m:

```
sudo apt-get install w3m
```

Comment: Please bring the relevant content of the link into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

the python guy is here now

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import webbrowser

query = " ".join(sys.argv[1:]).encode('utf-8')
print('Query: "{}"'.format(query))
webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(query))
```

Example usage:

```
$ google does this work?
query: "Does this work?"
```

Then it will open a web browser to this page

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to sign up for a [Google API key](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/signup.html), you should be able to use the [Net::Google](http://search.cpan.org/~ascope/Net-Google-1.0/lib/Net/Google.pm) Perl module in tandem with the Google SOAP API to do this. 
See [here](http://jeays.net/files/perlgoogle.htm) and [here](http://codeidol.com/other/google-hack/Programming-Google/Program-Google-with-the-NetGoogle-Perl-Module/) for simple perl scripts that use Net::Google.

You can also use the less specialised [SOAP::Lite](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=662483) perl module for this task.

Alternatively, you can screen scrape Google queries via WWW::Mechanize,  Web::Scraper or one of the many Perl screen-scraping modules, if you aren't disturbed by it's [nebulous legal standing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues). Here's a good [tutorial](http://linuxgazette.net/108/oregan2.html) to get you started.

A command-line tool like this might work well when combined with a browser like [Uzbl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzbl) to provide a fast browsing experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a terminal browser like [Elinks](http://www.xteddy.org/elinks/), which allows you to browse the web in the terminal and optionally open a link in another browser, like Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

With Mac OSX I use an alias in my .bash_profil  `alias google=sh ~/scripts/google.sh`

google.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -g /Applications/Safari.app "http://www.google.com/search?q=$*"
```

Usage:

```
google word1 word2 ...
```

This way works fine for me.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you use KDE environment with default settings, ypu could search from krunner (called by Alt-F2 command).

For searching for *query* on *Google*, type in the krunner textbox:

```
gg:query
```

For searching for *query* on *Wikipedia*, type in the krunner textbox:

```
wp:query
```

**Examples:**

```
Alt-F2 + gg:Google search from terminal
Alt-F2 + wp:stackoverflow
```

**Source:** https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner

Answer (score -1):

[Beagle](https://github.com/GNOME/beagle) can search from terminal. Or you've to look for browsers like [Elinks](http://www.xteddy.org/elinks/).

Comment: Beagle link is not working !!